# How to concatenate three values from different tables in c#

Tags: c#

I am using a C# Winforms application. I want to concatenate three values from three different tables into a single label.

I have tried this line of code to get values from tables but it is not working.

```
this.label15.Text = reader["CourseName" + "TeacherName" +"RoomName"].ToString();
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Try `= reader["CourseName"].ToString() + reader["TeacherName"].ToString() + reader["RoomName"].ToString();`

Comment: @Quantumplate it's better to use `String.Concat( reader["CourseName"].ToString(), reader["TeacherName"].ToString() ,reader["RoomName"].ToString());` or maybe `String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", reader["CourseName"], reader["TeacherName"], reader["RoomName"])`

Comment: @MihailStancescu Define "better".  It's unlikely to matter one way or the other.

Comment: @MihailStancescu definitely, I'd recommend String.Format() as they are unlikely to want the values joined directly.  The point is to access each one individually from the reader.

Comment: @Quantumplate Thankyou so much it worked, i need one more help, i want first text in one line then second text in other line and third text in other line. What should I need to add in this line of code?

Comment: @KyleW "better" means that the code it's more clearer and if I remember it correctly there is also a performance improvement. Of course this works if you want to concatenate few string variables if you need more then it's better to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Try... `string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", reader["CourseName"].ToString(), reader["TeacherName"].ToString());`  Where the `\r\n` is the newline.  This depends on whether your label can display multiple lines or not, I forget if they can or not.

Comment: @MihailStancescu clearer is subjective.  I have no problem reading the example.  As far as performance, direct concatenation with + is likely faster than using an uninitialized `StringBuilder`.  And again, in either case it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: @Fary That question should be a separate question.  I would also advise against using `"\r\n"` in any code.

Comment: @KyleW where i should write this? can u tell me in the code?

Comment: @Fary Use `Environment.NewLine`.  But if you have another question... write another question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will try to find a column `CourseNameTeacherNameRoomName`.  You need to get the 3 values separately, and then concatenate them.

```
this.label15.Text = reader["CourseName"].ToString() + reader["TeacherName"].ToString() + reader["RoomName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.label15.Text = reader["CourseName" + "TeacherName" +"RoomName"].ToString();` - this is wron and weird because your result key in table is `"CourseNameTeacherNameRoomName"`. Are you sure you have such a key in your tables somewhere?

To achive this just use one key name per access. Or, as sugessted by Mihail Stancescu in comments, you could use `String.Concat` method

**UPDATE**

According to your question in comment, to show each of your values in different values you need `String.Format` method:

`String.Format("{0},\r\n{1},\r\n{2}", reader["CourseName"], reader["TeacherName"], reader["RoomName"])` - this is a case with return and new line carriages; or with `Environment.NewLine`:

`String.Format("{0},{3}{1},{3}{2}", reader["CourseName"], reader["TeacherName"], reader["RoomName"], Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: can you tell me how I am able to show all values in different lines? I want to show CourseName in one line, TeacherName in other line and RoomName in other line?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me (the most flexible) is to use string.Format(...) method.

Simply write:

```
this.label15.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", reader["CourseName"], reader["TeacherName"], reader["RoomName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your values individually from the `reader` like so...

```
this.label15.Text = string.Format("{0}{3}{1}{3}{2}",
  reader["CourseName"].ToString(), 
  reader["TeacherName"].ToString(), 
  reader["RoomName"].ToString(), 
  System.Environment.NewLine);
```

I'm also using `string.Format()` to build the text you want and include the new lines which are represented by the {3} in the string and populated with `System.Environment.NewLine`.